Crypto RSA find p and q with a bitmask
Im new to Crypto and I am stuck in this challenge where I need to be able to somehow extract p and q.
You are given a python script and an output.txt with the ecnrypted flag and other relevant elemnts
This is the script you are given:
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

RSAkeys = RSA.generate(2048)
p = RSAkeys.p
q = RSAkeys.q
n = RSAkeys.n
e = RSAkeys.e
m = b"LetsCTF{<REDACTED>}"
c = pow(int.from_bytes(m, "big"), e, n)

mask = int("55" * 128, 16)
r = p & mask
mask = mask << 1
r += q & mask

print(f"n = {n}")
print(f"e = {e}")
print(f"c = {c}")
print(f"r = {r}")

The problem is I am not able to extract p and q from "n", "e", "c" and "r"
I understand the concept behind RSA but I'm still not able to solve it.
So far I've tried to make a script and try to get p and q from r.
The initial mask after mask = int("55" * 128, 16) is of the form 0101 0101 ... 0101 (a series of 5 in binary). Then r at this point: r = p & mask is an integer formed by the even bits of p. After rotating the mask to the left, the odd bits of q are added to r. Then r is an integer whose even bits are the even bits of q, and whose odd bits are the odd bits of q.
I wrote this script to obtain approximations of p and q (half the bits of each):
pa = ""
qa = ""
i = 0
for elem in bin(r).lstrip("0b"):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        pa+= elem
        qa+= '0'
    else:
        qa+= elem
        pa+= '0'
    i += 1


pa = int(pa,2)
qa = int(qa,2)

The even bits of r are assigned to pa (approximation of p) and qa is assigned 0 and the other way around for the odd bits.
So far I have not been able to complete pa and qa up to p and q. I know that pq is equal to "n" but I do not know how to modify pa and qa so that paqa converts to n.
Thanks for your attention and sorry for my bad English.

The problem is that I am not able to write a script that will test all the different combinations of the missing bits of p and q.

Here is a program demonstrating one method for recovering the unknown prime factors p and q of an RSA modulus n = p * q.
The basic idea is that the r value in your problem gives us every other bit of p and every other bit of q. Suppose we know the low-order B bits of p and q. Then we can write p = p12B + p0 and q = q12B + q0, so
n = pq = p1q122B + (p1q0 + p0q1)2B + p0q0, which, mod 2B, is equal to p0q0. In other words, the low-order B bits of n depend only on the low-order B bits of p and q. The algorithm increases the size of the known part of p and q by 2 bits at each iteration.
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/78578789/238704
import math
import random
import time

_PRIME_SIZE_BITS = 1024
_PRIME_SIZE_BYTES = _PRIME_SIZE_BITS // 8


def create_ctf_instance():
    primes = []
    while len(primes) < 2:
        prime = random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(_PRIME_SIZE_BITS) | 1
        if pow(2, prime - 1, prime) == 1 and pow(3, prime - 1, prime) == 1:  #  good enough for RSA-sized primes
            primes.append(prime)
    p, q = primes
    n = p * q
    e = 65537
    m = b"LetsCTF{<blah, blah, and blah>}"
    c = pow(int.from_bytes(m, "big"), e, n)
    mask = int("55" * _PRIME_SIZE_BYTES, 16)
    r = p & mask
    mask = mask << 1
    r += q & mask
    return n, e, c, r


def find_factors(n: int, cheat: int) -> tuple[int, int] | tuple[None, None]:
    """
    Assume n is the product of two primes p and q, each no larger than _PRIME_SIZE_BITS.
    Using the "cheat" value `cheat` which gives us 1/2 of the bits, find the unknown
    1/2 of the bits and return p and q.
    :param n:
    :param cheat:
    :return:
    """

    mask = int("55" * _PRIME_SIZE_BYTES, 16)
    survivors = {(1, 1)}
    current_bit_length = 0
    low_order_bitmask = 0x3
    #
    # build the prime factors of n, p and q, from the low-order bit to the
    # high-order bit two bits at a time. One of those bits for each prime
    # is provided by `cheat` and one we have to guess. We check our guess by
    # multiplying these low-order bits together and verifying that they
    # match the low-order bits of n
    #
    while current_bit_length < (n.bit_length() + 1) // 2:
        next_survivors = set()
        while survivors:
            p_start, q_start = survivors.pop()
            # place the next cheat bits into each prime candidate
            p_start |= (cheat & mask) & low_order_bitmask
            q_start |= (cheat & (mask << 1)) & low_order_bitmask
            # now guess the unknown bit in each of p and q and check the guess
            for next_p_bit in range(2):
                p = p_start | next_p_bit << (current_bit_length + 1)
                for next_q_bit in range(2):
                    q = q_start | next_q_bit << current_bit_length
                    if (p * q ^ n) & low_order_bitmask == 0:
                        next_survivors.add((p, q))
        survivors = next_survivors
        current_bit_length += 2
        low_order_bitmask = (low_order_bitmask << 2) | 0x3
    for p, q in survivors:
        if p * q == n:
            return p, q
    return None, None


def main():
    n, e, c, r = create_ctf_instance()
    start = time.process_time()
    p, q = find_factors(n, r)
    elapsed = time.process_time() - start
    if p is None:
        print("No factors found")
    else:
        print(f'found factors: \n\t{p}\n\t{q}\nin {elapsed} seconds')
        # compute d
        car_lam = math.lcm(p - 1, q - 1)
        d = pow(e, -1, car_lam)
        m = pow(c, d, n)
        print(m.to_bytes((m.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

